# Find address of a class member when debugging in VS

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2013

The story so far - I have some class. This class have some members of different types. In some function I set a breakpoint and now I want to see the address of members. But I can't - Locals window shows only values. Here's a picture:

[image]

As you can see - for ***this*** pointer I have memory address displayed (0x000000000bca0a40), but for anything inside it (InstanceBodyIndex for example) - no.

How can I obtain this addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the "Watch" window.

Add the variable you're interested in with the address-of operator in front, e.g. "&InstanceBodyIndex".

Answer (score 0):

Add one additional answer since moldbnilo's answer doesn't work perfectly for nest classes. (Tested with VS2015)

- Add watch for the outmost object
- Click to expand the object's nest member
- Right-click on the member's name, choose Add watch
- We will get one more watch name on the watch window(It's a generated
  expression and may be complex), name it as EXPR
- copy the EXPR, and wrapper it as &(EXPR), then we get the address of
  nest member

[image]